# How to find joint probability mass function of X and Y given marginal distribution of X and conditional distribution of Y given X.

Tags: probability-distributions

how can we find joint probability mass function of discrete random variables X and Y, if we are given marginal distribution of X as well as the the conditional distributions of Y given X ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: $P(X = m , Y = n) = P(X = m) \times P(Y = n | X = m)$ should help.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked for me ! Is there a way i can mark it as a solution.

Comment: You can mark what I've written below. If it feels like too little, then add a simple example to your question and  I will work it out if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have :

$$
P(X = m, Y = n) = \underbrace{P(X = m)}_{\text{marginal}}\underbrace{P(Y = n | X = m)}_{\text{conditional}}
$$

The marginal is given, the conditional is given, thus the joint is recovered. This step is often skipped even in elementary textbooks, so it is good you asked.